# SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',) when trying to deploy Kuberntes with Kubespray

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, kvm, kubespray, cri-o

Hello and thanks in advance for your help !

I am trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster using Kubespray (an ansible playbook). I am trying to deploy the Cluster on 17 KVM host (all nodes are running centos 7 , and are hosted on a baremetal server)

However , when I try to run the playbook at the task `[download : file_download | Download item]`
I get the following error (and thus stopping the installation) :

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)                                                                                                                              
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 4, "changed": false, "msg": "failed to create temporary content file: ('The read operation timed out',)"}
```

This error is the same for most of the node , BUT , some nodes are willing to downlaod.

Here is the error in verbose mode:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_get_url_payload_72qREk/__main__.py", line 360, in url_get
    shutil.copyfileobj(rsp, f)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 49, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 602, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 757, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 651, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)

fatal: [node14]: FAILED! => {
    "attempts": 4,
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "checksum": "",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": "/tmp/releases/kubeadm",
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": null,
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "mode": "0755",
            "owner": "root",
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "sha256sum": "c4fc478572b5623857f5d820e1c107ae02049ca02cf2993e512a091a0196957b",
            "src": null,
            "timeout": 10,
            "tmp_dest": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.1/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "failed to create temporary content file: ('The read operation timed out',)"
}
```

I tried to connect to the nodes and try to download an item (I tried to download the Kubspray zip) and it worked , all nodes reach the internet and can install package.

From the verbose output , I somewhat understood that the error come from python , but I really don't know how to solve it...

Let me know if I can give you another piece of information and angain , thanks in advance !

Comment: If "all nodes reach the Internet and can install package" then I'd guess your login shell is setting proxy variables that the ansible playbook is not setting

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. You may be able to get help on [sf].

Answer (score 4):

So , I "solved" the problem.

In fact , Ansbible has a timeout of 10 seconds for **all ssh related command/read/write** task.
For unknown reasons , the write task on my nodes was a bit slow , so I got this error.
Fortunately , you can change the time before a timeout.

You can either use the argument -T (or-tiemout ) 'time_wanted' or change the ansible.cfg.
The 'basic' cfg file is located in `etc/ansible/ansible.etc` , but be careful , some custom ansible playbook will have a custom ansible.cfg so you will need to find it and change it to your needs.

I was lucky , the 4 time I ran the playbook , it installed K8s smoothly.

For testing reason , I am running my nodes on KVM , so maybe the write slowness come from here.

Hope that someone will find my answer useful !

Comment: Just to add clarification: I came back to this problem a while later (After a deployed another cluster on AWS and after i had a deeper understanding of how kubernetes).And the my problem whe I was trying a cluster on premises was probabably the slow connection , who gave me errors when trying to download the huge binaries of kubernetes , if you have this problem , try to download the bin by hand , and make them accecible to your clusters